# How could one replicate this three.js effect in Blender - wave texture?

Tags: animation, image, gltf, effects

Is there any tutorial on how I could replicate such an image texture as seen on [this website](https://unshift.jp/works/tkmh) in Blender? I would love to embed it as a .glb file on my website.

Any tips on how I could go on about this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this shader node setup:

[image]

for a subdivided plane:

[image]

with this wave modifier:

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fiddly part might be getting the animation to loop. Maybe Geometry Nodes makes that more intuitive.. you can ensure there are an exact number of waves per loop-cycle more easily?

[image]

Here, the animation is 100 frames long. This GN group puts the sum of 2 radial waves through the Z offset of the vertices in a subdivided plane. The highlighted nodes ensure that the period of the waves divides 100 exactly.. the top one is `2PI/50`, the bottom one `2PI/100`. The last multiply in each branch sets the amplitude of the waves.

This is the sort of shading set-up.. yours will be different, I'm sure, I had to convert my logo to B/W.

[image]

The animated plane, shot against a white World..

[image]

Fine adjustments to the apparent depth of the distortion can be made using the focal-length of the camera lens.

[image]